# Beginner's Guide to configure VPN to work in Windows 7?

Tags: networking, windows-7, vpn

I'm trying to configure one of my machines to serve as a VPN and through it connect using Windows 7.

I installed `pptp` followed all the instructions but it keeps giving me error 619. I verified the ports and I allowed port 1723 in both tcp and udp so I'm quite unsure what's left to do

Is there a guide that has completely worked for you?

Comment: For official guides try these [Open Vpn](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN),[open Vpn 2](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/openvpn.html), [Vpn Client](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient) , [open Vpn Server](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNServer/)

Comment: Where is the "Ubuntu" part in your question?

Comment: @Lekensteyn what do you want to know? Ubuntu version? 12.04

Comment: Looking at the title, I'd think that this question belongs to superuser.com because it asks to get something done in Windows 7. However, when reading the question body, it becomes clear that you maybe want to configure an Ubuntu as VPN server. Is PPTP a requirement or can it be OpenVPN too?

Comment: @Lekensteyn Hmm perhaps but I don't think crossing questions will do good when there are more linux users over here that could have struggled with the same problem before. PPTP is working like a charm, I found my problem which is iptables, need to find the correct rules.

Answer (score 1):

This was the guide that I was going to use for my client. They aren't being responsive however so I'm not sure if it will work for you:

[Windows 7 PPTP setup](http://www.howtogeek.com/51237/setting-up-a-vpn-pptp-server-on-debian/)

If you're having issues with internet particularly you need to make sure that HTTP is allowed through your PPTP as the default seems to be to deny access.

Comment: That worked, though there's something wrong, followed it all but it still says "No internet access". At least I managed to get it recognized.

Answer (score 0):

After following chrisjleaf's answer, all I needed was the exact iptables rules to apply

So far this has worked for me

```
iptables -A INPUT -i ppp0 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT



iptables -A OUTPUT -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -d <VPN-LOCALIP> -p tcp --dport 1723 -j DNAT --to <VPN-REMOTEIP>
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -d <VPN-REMOTEIP> -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 1723 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth1 -d <VPN-LOCALIP> -p 47 -j DNAT --to <VPN-REMOTEIP>
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth1 -d <VPN-REMOTEIP> -p 47 -j ACCEPT
```

Remember to replace `VPN-REMOTEIP` and  `VPN-LOCALIP`

then `iptables-save`

Comment: `iptables-save` is not necessary to apply these rules. `iptables-save` stores the rule in a file which can be restored later with `iptables-restore`.